# Python scikit learn decision tree

Tags: python, scikit-learn

`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import *
from sklearn.model_selection import *
from sklearn.metrics import *
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from seaborn import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {"Outlook" : ["Sunny", "Sunny", "Overcast", "Rain", "Rain", "Rain", "Overcast", "Sunny", "Sunny", "Rain", "Sunny", "Overcast", "Overcast", "Rain"],
     "Temperature" : ["Hot", "Hot", "Hot", "Mild", "Cool", "Cool", "Cool", "Mild", "Cool", "Mild", "Mild", "Mild", "Hot", "Mild"],
     "Humidity" : ["High", "High", "High", "High", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "High", "Normal", "Normal", "Normal", "High", "Normal", "High"],
     "Wind" : ["Weak", "Strong", "Weak", "Weak", "Weak", "Strong", "Strong", "Weak", "Weak", "Weak", "Strong", "Strong", "Weak", "Strong"],
     "Played football(yes/no)" : ["No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No"]}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(d)
lb = LabelEncoder()
dataframe["Outlook"] = lb.fit_transform(dataframe["Outlook"])

lz = LabelEncoder()
dataframe["Temperature"] = lz.fit_transform(dataframe["Temperature"])

la = LabelEncoder()
dataframe["Humidity"] = la.fit_transform(dataframe["Humidity"])

lc = LabelEncoder()
dataframe["Wind"] = lc.fit_transform(dataframe["Wind"])

lh = LabelEncoder()
dataframe["Played football(yes/no)"] = lh.fit_transform(dataframe["Played football(yes/no)"])

x = dataframe[["Outlook", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Wind"]]
y = dataframe["Played football(yes/no)"]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)

d = DecisionTreeClassifier()
d.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = d.predict(x_test)

cf = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

z = plot_tree(d, filled=True, feature_names=x.columns)
plt.show()
`
```

[image: Decision tree]

From the picture, the outlook that are not less than 0.5 will go to the right side and same to other condition. But, how should I calculate whether the outlook less than or greater than 0.5 since it is not numerical data?

Comment: What is `less than or greater`?

Comment: At the root node, the outlook <= 0.5

Comment: your values of outlook is 0,1 and 2 after encoding. Thats why DT has made threshold of  0.5 and 1.5. So range lies between 0-0.5, 0.5-1.5, 1.5-2. Anything between 0-0.5 will be 0, 0.5-1.5 will be 1 and 1.5-2 will be 2.

Comment: question is not about programming

Answer (score 0):

After your transformation (`label encoder`), all your features are numerical, so the decision will use this numerical values of the features (included `outlook`)

To sump up, when you are using a decision tree form sklearn, **all the features and split will be based on numerical values**.